# how to get subset of matrix in class numpy.matrix.defmatrix.matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

The original matrix variable is N and the shape is (138, 210).
I tried to use N[:][:-1] and N[:][-1] to get the subset of this matrix N.
So the shape of these two subsets would be (138,209) and (138,1).
However, this method does not work. The response is (137,210) and (1,210).
I also tried N[:-1][:], but this does not work neither.

The type of N is numpy.matrix.defmatrix.matrix

How can I get the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
In [42]: N = np.random.rand(138, 210)

In [43]: N[:, :-1].shape
Out[43]: (138L, 209L)

In [44]: N[:, -1].shape
Out[44]: (138L,)
```

`N[:, :-1]` for `(138, 209)` shape and `N[:, -1]` for `(138, 1)` shape.

Answer (score 1):

To select all rows and all-but-the-last column:

```
N[:, :-1]
```

To select from each row just the last column:

```
N[:, -1]
```

`N[:, :-1]` will have shape `(138, 209)`, and `N[:, -1]` will have shape `(138, 1)`.

[This cookbook page](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Indexing#head-27eebcd1d3fdc7f10c2f20a0cfb3ca703096e2ab) explains multidimensional slicing.

---

**Why `N[:][:-1]` returns an array with one less row**:

Slicing `N` defaults to slicing along the first axis. So `N[:]` slices along the axis of length 138. As you can see above, to slice along the second axis, you need to supply two slice expressions separated by a comma: e.g. `N[:, :-1]`. The second slice expression, `:-1` is applied to the second axis.

`N[:]` returns a slice of `N` containing all the rows (and since no slicing is performed along the second axis, it also returns all the columns). It is a view of the same matrix `N`. So `N[:]` has shape `(138, 210)`. `N[:][:-1]` is thus selecting all but the last row of `N` and hence has shape `(137, 210)`.